# How to Call Function in SQLAlchment Query Statement?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Can I call function in SQLAlchemy like this?

```
db.session.query(User).update({'spotify_date':format_date(User.spotify_date)})
db.session.commit()
```

Here I tried to call function `format_date()` to format date in column `spotify_date` of relation table `User`.

Here is **user models**

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    spotify_id = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=False, nullable=True)
    spotify_token = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=False, nullable=True)
    spotify_date = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=False, nullable=True)
```

And function `fomate_date()` and call of function

```
from app import app, db, User

def format_date(date):
    """Format date to local format: dd-mm-yyyy
    
    Args:
        date (String): spotify_date
    
    Returns:
        string: date formatted in local

    Examples:
    >>> formate_date('2020-07-18')
    '18-07-2020'
    
    """
    dateList = date.split('-')
    dateList.reverse()

    return '-'.join(dateList)



db.session.query(User).update({'spotify_date':format_date(User.spotify_date)})
db.session.commit()
```

After that I got an exception as:

> AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor
> 'Comparator' object associated with User.spotify_date has an attribute
> 'split'

Anyway, how I can correctly do this in SQLAlchemy query statement? Thanks

**P.S:** The database I am using is Postgresql; the function is the python function, not database function. Thanks.

Comment: What database do you use? In short: what you are trying to achieve is possible but it requires using SQL functions not Python.

Comment: @SergeyShubin, I have editted to add more detail on question. I am using database Postgresql, and the function is python function. The reason I decided to use this function in database query statement because I would like this task to be handled by database rather than by python script because there would thousand of record which would slow down the server. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make an UPDATE query which updates several rows you need to pass a single expression (value, function etc.) to this query. Python function won't do because your database doesn't know this particular function. So you need to convert your `format_date` function to the SQL expression and pass it to your query:

```py
from app import db, User

format_date = (db.func.substr(User.spotify_date, 9, 2) + '-' +
               db.func.substr(User.spotify_date, 6, 2) + '-' +
               db.func.substr(User.spotify_date, 1, 4))
db.session.query(User).update({'spotify_date': format_date}, synchronize_session=False)
db.session.commit()
```

SQLAlchemy [func](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.func) function allow you to use internal database functions. `format_date` function looks like this in pure SQL:

```sql
SUBSTR("user"."spotify_date", 9, 2) || '-' || SUBSTR("user"."spotify_date", 6, 2) || '-' || SUBSTR("user"."spotify_date", 1, 4)
```

Also note that this function works for columns of `String` (`VARCHAR`) type. For `DateTime` (`TIMESTAMP`) type it would be different.

---

In order to apply *Python* function to the values from the table you need to get these values first. After that you have to apply the function and make an UPDATE for every single row. It would be rather long as you have noticed.

Comment: thank you very much, I have tested your answer and it worked just as expected.